# onChildRemoved keeps calling when I delete child from other activity

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Im using firebase android and I have a problem while getting inside other acitivy to delete few childs. The method `onChildRemoved` called when I inside the activity the method is at. I undrestand that.

However I don't undrestand why I returned back to the method call once I used Intent to get out from the activity where the method `onChildRemoved`is in.

How can I disable calls from `onChildRemoved`method when being in other activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're using `addChildEventListener` to attach the listener, which means that the listener remains active until you explicitly remove it. Changing activities does not automatically remove the listener.

What you can do is remove the listener on for example the `onPause` method, by calling the [`removeEventListener` method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Query#removeEventListener(com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener)) on the same reference/query that you added it to.

So for example if you add it with something like:

```
listener = new ChildEventListener() {
  @Override
  public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot snapshot, String previousChildName) {
    ...
}
ref.addChildEventListener(listener);
```

Then you can later remove it with:

```
ref.removeEventListener(listener);
```